# decNumber library - compile issues

Tags: c++, decimal-point

I am having issues compiling the decNumber http://speleotrove.com/decimal/, source is here http://download.icu-project.org/files/decNumber/decNumber-icu-368.zip (includes examples etc. that need to be deleted)

Has anyone compiled this successfully? Your comments will be much appreciated!!

The compiler issues an error as a result of the following directives:

```
#if !defined(QUAD)
#error decBasic.c must be included after decCommon.c
#endif
```

(This is a small section of code from decCommon.c and decBasic.c is another source file)

The author of the code states in comments that these 2 source files are shared. There are no corresponding .h files.

I am on Windows 7 64 bit, compiling with Visual Studio 2010 32 bit.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You may want to try std::decimal::decimal32, etc... ...since it has been added to the C++ std.

Comment: I suspect you are referring to GCC compiler? I believe they added the type (which actually runs on decNumber under the hood!) But I am fairly certain the decimal type never made it into the standard, so I doubt Visual Studio would support it. In either case, thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decBasic.c and decCommon.c are #included at the BOTTOM of the specific implementation files (such as decDouble.c). So - you shouldn't compile decBasic.c or decCommon.c, but treat them like header files.

If you look at the MAKE file included, you can see what the compilation targets are: decBasic and decCommon are missing.

If you are using Visual Studio, you can add decBasic.c and decCommon.c as headers, so they appear in the project but will not be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

decNumber is not in a compilable state in its original form as it requires some source code modifications to include standard integer types.
QDecimal library handles this issue by using slightly modified version of decNumber.
Please see QDecimal project for details:

http://code.google.com/p/qdecimal/

http://code.google.com/p/qdecimal/source/browse/doc/INSTALL.txt

Comment: Note that QDecimal relies on QT, meaning it is not a standalone C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling with `Visual Studio 2010` do not include `decBasic.c` and `decCommmon.c` to the project. These files are include-only and should not be compiled separately. In my case I am using `decDouble` module only and my project is setup as follows:

- Header Files

  - `decContext.h`
  - `decDouble.h`
  - `decDPD.h`
  - `decnumberlocal.h`
  - `decQuad.h`
- Source Files

  - `decContext.c`
  - `decDouble.c`
  - `decQuad.c`

Additionally files `decBasic.c` and `decCommon.c` are in the same directory where `decQuad.c` is located.