# decNumber C library Visual Studio 2010 Compile error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, decimal

I am getting errors compiling the [decNumber](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html) C library in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 64
-bit PC.

I already tried the solutions offered at this post:
[decNumber library - compile issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337351/decnumber-library-compile-issues) but did not fix my problems.

These are the errors I am getting

```
error C1189: #error :  Unexpected DECPMAX value
```

coming from this line of code in delCommonn.c file:

```
//names for simpler testing and default context
   #if DECPMAX==7
  #define SINGLE     1
  #define DOUBLE     0
  #define QUAD       0
  #define DEFCONTEXT DEC_INIT_DECIMAL32
#elif DECPMAX==16
  #define SINGLE     0
  #define DOUBLE     1
  #define QUAD       0
  #define DEFCONTEXT DEC_INIT_DECIMAL64
#elif DECPMAX==34
  #define SINGLE     0
  #define DOUBLE     0
  #define QUAD       1
  #define DEFCONTEXT DEC_INIT_DECIMAL128
#else
  #error Unexpected DECPMAX value
#endif
```

also getting this error:

```
error C1189: #error :  decBasic.c must be included after decCommon.c
```

from line of code in delBasic.c file:

```
// The compile-time flags SINGLE, DOUBLE, and QUAD are set up in
// decCommon.c
#if !defined(QUAD)
  #error decBasic.c must be included after decCommon.c
#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Which file are you compiling when you get the error — one provided by the library or one of your own creation?  The error message is clear enough; the file  `decBasic.c` must be included after `decCommon.c`.  The cross-referenced question shows that you must not compile `decBasic.c` or `decCommon.c` to object files; they are more of the nature of header files, for all they end with `.c`.

Comment: How do I include the decBasic.c before decCommon.c file before compiling?  I included both files as header files in my VS10 project.